# How can I display the results in a ListBox instead of a ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms

The follwing code works well working for `lvwResult`, but how can I display the  results in `listbox1`?

I just want to use `listbox1` only, instead of `lvwResult`.

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath != "")
    {
        txtDirectory.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }
}

private void btnClose_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close ();
}

private void btnSearchNow_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MLSecurityFinder     lSecFinder = new MLSecurityFinderClass ();
    int                  iCounter = 0;

    lvwResult.Items.Clear ();

    lSecFinder.bScanSubDirectories = chkSubfolders.Checked;

    try
    {
       lSecFinder.FindSecurity (txtSymbol.Text, txtDirectory.Text);
       while (lSecFinder.bSecLeft)
       {
          ListViewItem   lItem = lvwResult.Items.Insert (iCounter, lSecFinder.SecName);
          lItem.SubItems.Add (lSecFinder.SecSymbol);
          lItem.SubItems.Add (lSecFinder.SecFileName);

          lSecFinder.FindNextSecurity();

          iCounter++;
        }
     }
     catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ComEx)
     {
        //MessageBox.Show (ComEx.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
        lSecFinder.DestroySearchDialog ();
     }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

List boxes don't support multiple columns, unless you're planning on owner-drawing your listbox items. So you'll need to start by deciding how you're going to map your old multi-column data to a single string. Let's say, for the sake of argument, that you decide to combine the used-to-be-columns with commas, so that each of your listbox items would look like "SecName,SecSymbol,SecFileName".

That's the only part that's likely to be at all mysterious. From here, it's just like solving any other problem. You want to replace usages of lvwResult with usages of listbox1? Sounds like a job for search-and-replace to me. Then fix whatever doesn't compile. The code that builds your columns (SubItems) definitely won't compile, but by this point, you will have already decided what to do with that, so it's just a matter of writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a sample on adding items to the listbox.

```
    public class SampleData {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Now you have the code of:

```
        List<SampleData> sampleList = new List<SampleData>() { 
            new SampleData() { Id = 1, Name = "Peyton" }
        };

        listBox1.DataSource = sampleList;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Or you can have it directly using the items property.

```
        listBox1.Items.Add(new SampleData() { Id = 1, Name = "Sample" });
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```